# How to merge these two DataFrames

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],
                       'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                       'B': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
right = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1'],})
#left df                         #right df
    A   B   key                        key
0   1   1   K0                     0   K0  
1   2   2   K1                     1   K1
3   3   3   K2
4   4   4   K3
```

First I want to create a DataFrame only contains K0,K1

```
first = pd.merge(left, right, on='key')
#first df
    A   B   key                  
0   1   1   K0                     
1   2   2   K1
```

Then I want to create a DataFrame only contains K2,K3

```
#Expectation df
    A   B   key
0   3   3   K2
0   4   4   K3
```

I realized this should be done by left(right) outer method,but I am confused about this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isin` to build a boolean mask:

```
mask = left['key'].isin(right['key'])
```

Then use `.loc[mask]` to select rows based on the mask:

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],
                       'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                       'B': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
right = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1'],})
mask = left['key'].isin(right['key'])
first, second = left.loc[mask], left.loc[~mask]
```

yields

```
In [88]: first
Out[88]: 
   A  B key
0  1  1  K0
1  2  2  K1

In [89]: second
Out[89]: 
   A  B key
2  3  3  K2
3  4  4  K3
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I prefer to do this kind of merge and search is:
first, you set the index on the key (which are very similar concepts at the beginning, right?):

```
left.set_index('key',inplace=True)
right.set_index('key',inplace=True)
```

Then when you merge or join two DataFrames in pandas, you want to use pd.concat http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html, which is method pandas uses for all the merge and join operations (pandas join and merge method also use this under the hood.)

```
In[10]: pd.concat([left,right], axis=1)
Out[10]: 
    A  B
K0  1  1
K1  2  2
K2  3  3
K3  4  4
```

Now, you can easily select the key you want:

```
In[17]: df = pd.concat([left,right], axis=1)
In[18]: df.loc[['K0','K1'],:]
Out[18]: 

    A  B
K0  1  1
K1  2  2
```